# Specifying a font in AutoComplete TextBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

Has anyone managed to modify the default font size for a AutoComplete TextBox, Windows Forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the underline Windows API does not have an option to change the font size. If you need to customize the suggest list's appearance you need to implement autocomplete by yourself.

Suggested reading:[AUTOCOMPLETEOPTIONS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762479%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thought as much after some reading, thanks for your response Sheng.

Comment: Jiang: You look like spent lot of time on Autocomplete feature, have gone though your answers on microsoft answers and your blog explaining implementing own autocomplete object.